# Как в WP передать данные из формы JS и отправить на email

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Задача тривиальна для лендингов. Но лэндинг на WP, данные JS отправляю через POST на эту же страницу со скриптом PHP. Как сделать более рационально и адекватно через админку WP?

Comment: В чем именно проблема?

Comment: Как правильно, в пределах сайта на WP, передать данные из формы JS, в скрипт на php, где и как лучше его разместить, так как сейчас он просто подключается на нужных страницах сайта прям в шаблоне, что определено не есть удобно. Ошибка в скрипте и надо на большом количестве страниц исправлять эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы пошел по пути:

- Создать свою функцию отправки email при заполнении формы в functions.php
- Написать собственный js, который будет вызывать через ajax нашу функцию отправки и обрабатывать ответ.
- Поместить наш js в отдельный файл и подключить его в functions.php через wp_enque_scripts()

Пример записи на курс, отправляет данніе на емейл администратора сайта:
Код functions.php который отправляет емейл администратору

```
add_action('wp_ajax_course_feedback', 'course_feedback_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_course_feedback', 'course_feedback_callback');
function course_feedback_callback() {
    $qty = intval($_POST['qty']);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $to = get_option('admin_email');
    $subject = 'Регистрация на вебинар: '.$course;
    $body = _e('Здравствуй Администратор, этот человек желает зарегистрироватся на вебинар, вот его данные:').'<br>
            <table width="600px">
            <tr><th>'._e('Вебинар').'<th><td>'.$course.'</td></tr>
            <tr><th>'._e('Имя').'<th><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
            <tr><th>'._e('Эл. адрес').'<th><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
            <tr><th>'._e('Контактный номер телефона').'<th><td>'.$tel.'</td></tr>
            <tr><th>'._e('Количество мест').'<th><td>'.$qty.'</td></tr>
            <tr><th>'._e('Цена за место').'<th><td>'.$price.'</td></tr>
            </table>';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $result = (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) ? true : false;
    if ($result==false) {
        $result = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
    }
    echo $result;
    wp_die();
}
```

Далее, создаем скрипт-обработчик отправки формы course.js(проверяет поля ли заполнены, берет значения для отправки, вызывает нашу функцию )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var empty = true;
    var redirect = $('#redirect').val();

    $('#email').focusout(function(){
        $('#email').filter(function(){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            if( !emailReg.test( email ) ) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
                empty = true;
            } else {
                $(this).css('background', 'none');
                empty = false;
            }
        })
    });

    $('.phone-format').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        var curchr = this.value.length;
        var curval = $(this).val();

        if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf('(') <= -1) {
            $(this).val('(' + curval + ')' + '-');
        } else if (curchr == 4 && curval.indexOf('(') > -1) {
            $(this).val(curval + ')-');
        } else if (curchr == 5 && curval.indexOf(')') > -1) {
            $(this).val(curval + '-');
        } else if (curchr == 9) {
            $(this).val(curval + '-');
            $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
        }
    });

    $('#name, #email, #tel').blur(function() {
        var value = $.trim(this.value).length;
        if(!value) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    $('#name, #email, #tel').keyup(function () {
        var value = $.trim(this.value).length;
        if(value>0){
            $(this).css('background', 'none');
            empty = false;
        } else if(!value) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    $('.send').on('click', function () {
        if(empty==false) {
            var data = {
                action: 'course_feedback',
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                qty: 1,
                price: $('.value[itemprop="price"]').attr('content'),
                tel: $('#tel').val(),
                course: $('#course').val()
            }
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                if(response==1){
                    $('.register').empty();
                    $('.register').html('<div class="success">Ваш запрос на регистрацию в тренинге '+ data['course'] +' успешно отослан. Через несколько секунд Вас перенаправит на страницу оплаты.</div>');
                    if(redirect!='0'){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.location.href = redirect;
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                } else {
                    $('.register').empty();
                    $('.register').html('<div class="error">Произошла ошибка. Перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте ещё.</div>');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.alert').css('background-color', 'pink');
            $('.alert').css('zoom', '1.1');
            $('.alert').css('margin-bottom', '15px');

        }
    });

    $(function() {
        $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
            $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-popup-open');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
            $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
            var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-popup-close');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Также подключаем наш скрипт на нужных записях, в functins.php

```
function course_js(){
    if( is_single() && get_post_type()=='lp_course' )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'course-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/assets/js/course.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), THIM_THEME_VERSION, true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'course_js');
```